# Why doesn't my function detect a correct input selection?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write a JavaScript function that will check if correct answer is chosen in list and then will print either answer is right or not.
I came up with this -
HTML code:

```
<select id="q1" style="background-color: #b0f1f1">
        <option value="1">Saulkrasti Beach</option>
        <option value="2">Jurmala Beach</option>
        <option value="3">Ventspils Beach</option>
    </select>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

Javascript code:

```
function rightchoice()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("q1");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == 2) {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Right Answer";
    }
}
```

But it does not print anything.

Comment: use DOM addEventListener with on Change attr

Comment: Do you call rightChoice somewhere?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events.

Comment: You'll want to do two things to further your understanding of the situation. 1) Learn how to  use your browser's source inspector to set breakpoints and debug your script. 2) Ask yourself what the logical flow of your script is. There's nothing here that would cause your function to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function rightchoice() {
  var e = document.getElementById("q1");
  var value = e.value;
  if (value == 2) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Right Answer";
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Wrong Answer";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="q1" style="background-color: #b0f1f1" onchange="rightchoice()">
  <option value="1">Saulkrasti Beach</option>
  <option value="2">Jurmala Beach</option>
  <option value="3">Ventspils Beach</option>
</select>
<p id="answer">This is answer</p>
```

Comment: An event handler would be much better than inline scripting.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an eventListener to your select listen for a change.

I have added here an else part to reset the value to an empty string when the wrong choice was selected.

```js
function rightchoice()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("q1");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == 2) {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Right Answer";
    }else{
       document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
const fom = document.getElementById("q1");
fom.addEventListener("change", rightchoice);
```

```html
<select  id="q1" style="background-color: #b0f1f1">
        <option value="1">Saulkrasti Beach</option>
        <option value="2">Jurmala Beach</option>
        <option value="3">Ventspils Beach</option>
    </select>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should add an event `onChange` where you will call your function

```
const selection = document.getElementById("q1");
selection.addEventListener("change", rightchoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('q1').addEventListener('change', function() {
var newVal = this.value;
if (newVal == 2) {
document.getElementById('answer').innerText = "Right answer.";
} else {
document.getElementById('answer').innerText = "Wrong answer.";
}
});
```

```html
<select id="q1" style="background-color: #b0f1f1">
        <option value="1">Saulkrasti Beach</option>
        <option value="2">Jurmala Beach</option>
        <option value="3">Ventspils Beach</option>
    </select>
<p id="answer"></p>
```